# PHP Namespace: Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, namespaces

are their already PHP frameworks that are using namespaces. I only now that their is zend who are working on it.

Best Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

Flow3 does. So will Symfony2. Lithium as well.

I expect all of the next-gen frameworks (e.g. those requiring PHP 5.3) to use namespaces.

Comment: I've taken a look on typo3 today. I knew that it exists, but never heard about someone who uses it. However, I think it looks pretty good. Does anyone have experiences with it?

Comment: @Sebastian Typo3 is one of the major CMS. Experience in it is often asked for in job offers. Flow3 on the other hand hasn't gained that much traction outside the Typo3 community. Not sure if that will change anytime soon.

Comment: @johnwards: Actually, Doctrine2 is a framework (or library if you want to call it that instead). It is a framework for building an ORM (although it includes a very good data mapper implementation itself) if you want to use it that way. It also comes with other useful utilities that you can use today under the "common" namespace. There is also a database abstraction layer that can be used in isolation as well.